# React native-How to pass data across different screens in TabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, tabnavigator

I have a TabNavigator that contains 2 screens, `PlanScreen and Recherchescreen`, in Recherchescreen I use fetch api to get data,and to display some of them so i want to passe some of this data in my `Planscreen without the need to use fetch` also on this screen.
the code looks like this:

```
import RechercheScreen from './RechercheScreen'
class PlanScreen extends React.Component {
    render(){
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
           <MapR/>
        </View>
      );
    }
  
  }

  class ListMed extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      
      <tab.Navigator swipeEnabled={false}>
          <tab.Screen name="Recherche" component={RechercheScreen} />
          <tab.Screen name="Plan" component={PlanScreen}/> 
      </tab.Navigator>
      
    );
  }
```

on my RechercheScreen:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._Request();
  }
  _Request = () => {
    
    fetchLien(*************).then((res) => {
      
      console.log("****************");
      console.log(res.medecin[0].obj);
      console.log("****************");
      this.setState({
        dataSource:res.medecin,
       
      })
    })
  }
render() {
    return (
<View>
 <Text > {res.medecin[0].obj.id}</Text>
<View>
)
```

let's take for example the id displayed on this screen, how can I passe it?
any suggestions are more than welcome!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass these params to other screens while navigating.

> Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second
> parameter to the navigation.navigate function:
> navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })
>
> Read the params in your screen component: route.params.

Example:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('PlanScreen', { myId: Your id })
         // OR
this.props.navigation.setParams({myId: Your id})
```

And this is the way you can get these `params on your PlaneScreen`

```
this.props.route.params.myId
```

[Link to React-Navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

Comment: thanks you for your reply, but its a tabnavigator, i dont use this.props.navigation.navigate to navigate to planScreen i just scroll horizontally.enlighten me if i m wrong.

Comment: I have added set params example in my answer.

Comment: should i put setParams in a function or oncall something? and setParam  accepts a route to where pass the id?

Comment: just setParams in your componentDIdMount or when you are fetching the data from api.